# The method openShiftsRequests return Resource not found for the segment 'openShiftsRequests'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Im try to get the pending shifts to approve in teams with api.

[Pending shifts teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYUA8.png)

Reading the API i think the correct method is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/openshiftchangerequest-list?view=graph-rest-1.0

When I try to get this method using the graph explore the response request is :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'openShiftsRequests'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-04T17:33:34",
            "request-id": "52f61a88-7f43-4653-9162-c8e90fc5998f"
        }
    }
}
```

My request is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/MY_TEAM_ID_WITH_SHIFT/schedule/openShiftsRequests

What can I do wrong??

Comment: Where's the `change`?

Comment: the change is not running now, and receive this error.

Comment: the example you hyperlinked reads *GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/schedule/openShifts**Change**Requests*. The message reads *Resource not found for the segment 'openShiftsRequests'*: no **Change**.